# Express and socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a problem when i use socket.io in get method, sockets emits two or three times, look:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res, next){

    res.render('index');

    io.on('connection', function(socket){

         socket.emit('hello'); // socket emits two or three times to client
    });
});
```

But if place socket outside get method, socket works correctly:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res, next){

    res.render('index');
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){

    socket.emit('hello'); // socket emits one time
});
```

I need place socket in get because I need to send the value of session to the client. Any proposition?